# Jslider not working properly on JSfiddle

Tags: jsfiddle

I am trying to work on jsfiddle with JSlider. I included Jquery.js and JSlider.js and the css. The problem is it shows the slider. But I can't move the slider.

The `fiddle` link is [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunsankars1989/ug28Z/)

Please check and help me. I am new with fiddle

Comment: i think you should update jSlider.js version..

Comment: @silk_route11, Got it now. I added some more js and css files which was there in the template